# Something is wrong with my vector source format

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wfs

I have been having a hard time with getting my WFS URL to go inside of OpenLayers. Here is the code I have. Am I missing anything? It looks correct to me. It must be something due to logic.

```
wfs_url = 'http://localhost:2222/geoserver/CAICWeb/wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.1.0' +
              '&request=GetFeature' +
              '&typename=CAICWeb:hospitals&' +
              '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:2231&' +
              ',EPSG:2231';

              
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent) {
          return 'http://localhost:2222/geoserver/CAICWeb/wfs?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.1.0' +
              '&request=GetFeature' +
              '&typename=CAICWeb:hospitals&' +
              '&CQL_FILTER=' + cqlfilter + '&' +
              'outputFormat=application/json' +
              '&srsname=EPSG:2231&' + ',EPSG:2231';
        },
        strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
      });

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
      });
```

Comment: Too many questions: do you see network call(s) to your webservice in the browser debugger Network panel? Did you set a proxy to bypass same origin issue in Ajax (I assumed your OpenLayers app is not running on the same port as Geoserver?!)? Do you have any payload returns from this http call(s) and if yes what it is (again look in browser debugger Network panel) ?

Comment: You are missing the bbox. `+ ',EPSG:2231';` should be  `+ 'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:2231';`

Comment: tried that..didn't work.howeer when its renders in the browser and i paste it in the CQL layer on geoserver, it gives me a parsing error which refers to this line of code that i stated earlier var cqlfilter = 'DWITHIN(geometry, collectGeometries(queryCollection(\'CAICWeb:mountain\',\'geometry\',\'name = \'\'' + document.getElementById('mountain').value + '\'\')), ' + document.getElementById('distance').value + ', feet)';